# Accessing netcdf4 files on Azure

Tags: python, azure, azure-data-factory, netcdf4

I've got a python script running on Microsoft Azure Batch service in the Data Factory. I'm now testing to see whether I can load and access netcdf4 files. However, as soon as I add "import netCDF4 as nc" to the top of my .py file, the debug in my Data Factory Pipeline fails and in the stderr file I get:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "main.py", line 5, in 
import netCDF4 as nc
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'netCDF4'

Is netcdf4 supported in Azure? If so, how do I install the module. I've tried adding *cmd /c "pip install azure-storage-blob pandas netCDF4"* to the "Start task settings" of my Batch pool, but no luck!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the command line use pip install netCDF4, it automatically takes care of any other dependencies such as the C libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing your error from my vscode terminal by adding below line in my imports:

```
import netCDF4 as nc
```

When I tired to do pip install and ran my .py file, Error message has been thrown as Module not found.

Now I found the problem, first we need to activate the virtual environment in python (CMD or VSCODE)
Below are the commands for to activate it:

```
python -m venv .venv
.venv\Scripts\activate
```

Now I did pip install netCDF4, It got successfully installed.

Below is the screenshot for it:
[image]